# Android onBackPressed

Tags: android

I have a Listactivity (ListView) and a search on the ListActivity. When I click on any row in the ListActivity it launches the Activity2.

The problem is, When I search on the ListActivity I have the searched results.When I click on any row in the searched results,it launches the Activity2. When I click back from the Activity2 it launches the ListActivity instead of lauching the searched results.

The reason is when OnBack is pressed the onResume is called on the ListActivity, which populates the adapter with the entire list.

Can anyone guide me on how to launch the searched results when onBack is pressed?

Comment: if I understood correctly, you should save result and when go back - restore it. but for more info need to see code, hard to say without seeing it.

Comment: add your code also and what your error in logcat

Comment: Please post your code. i think you are doing some work in onResume() of FirstActivity.

Comment: I managed to save the last typed query in a variable.Then when on back is pressed, I did a search on the query after populating the list. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are just opening Activity2 and then coming back to Activity1, there is no need to save state and restore it. Just add some more code "that will take the search query from `EditText` and make a search **automatically**" in your `onResume()` method **after** the code that populates the list

Answer (score 0):

Restore from Bundle object.

Please check [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Answer (score 0):

Easy mode solution would be setting your search query in onSaveInstanceState and restore it after recreation of activity in onRestoreInstanceState

Check ref : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#SaveState

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to do not call `finish()` in ListActivity before start new one.
2) In the SecondActivity you should call finish in `onBackPressed()`.

---

```
//1)
private void startSecondActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
    //put some Extra if needed
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

```
//2)
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to save the last typed query in a variable.Then when on back is pressed, I did a search on the query after populating the list.